# probability of choosing $k$ linear independent elements from a finite field

Tags: probability, probability-theory, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ denote a finite field with $q$ elements. What is the probability of choosing $k$ linear independet elements from $\mathbb{F}_q^n$?

I guess, it depends on how we choose from $\mathbb{F}_q^n$. If so, what's a considerable technique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"I guess, it depends on how we choose..." Yes, that's true.  From a linear algebraic perspective the most natural way is to divide the number of linearly independent ordered $k$-tuples of vectors from $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ by the total number of $k$-tuples.  (In more probabilistic language: you choose with replacement, and the order of the choices does matter.)  The latter number is easy: it's $(q^n)^k = q^{nk}$.

Do you want help computing the numerator?  I would suggest you start with the cases $k =1$ and $k =2$ and employ the following technique: fill up your $k$-tuple one vector at a time.  At each stage, count the number of ways you can add one more vector while maintaining linear independence.  For instance, you have $q^n-1$ choices for the first vector because you can choose anything but $0$ to get a linearly independent $1$-tuple.  For the second vector you don't want a scalar multiple of the first.  There are $q$ scalar multiples of any nonzero vector in $\mathbb{F}_q^n$, so you have $q^n -q$ choices for the second vector.  And so on...

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Let me try to conclude: If I want to choose $k$ linear independent vectors from $\mathbb{F}_q^n$, then there are $$q^n-q^i$$ choices for the $i-th$ vector. Thus, there are $$\sum_{i=1}^k \left(q^n-q^i\right)$$ choices at all. Now, we need to know, how many $k$-tuples of vectors from $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ exists. Maybe I misunderstood you, but I don't think this number equals $(q^n)^k$. In fact, this number should be $$\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (q^k-q^i)$$ But I don't think we are interested in this number at all. Please take a look at my second comment.

Comment: Each tuple implies an ordering. But from my point of view, the order shouldn't be interesting. However, we should be interested in the number of linear subspaces of dimension $k$. This number is given by $$G(n,k)=\frac{N(n,k)}{N(k,k)}=\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \left(q^n-q^i\right)}{\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \left(q^k-q^i\right)}$$ where $N(n,k)$ and $N(k,k)$ are the numbers of linear independent $k$-tuples from $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ and $S\le \mathbb{F}_q^n$ with $\text{dim }S=k$, respectively. Thus, the probability of choosing $k$ linear elements should be $$1-\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(q^n-q^i)}{G(n,k)}$$

Comment: @oxbadfood: 1) When you have independent choices to make, you multiply, not add.  2) The number of ordered $k$-tuples of elements from a set $X$ is $(\#X)^k$.  This is where the denominator comes from.  3) "But from my point of view, the order shouldn't be interesting." You didn't specify in your question that you wanted unordered tuples.  The computation that I did above is a standard one that, in particular when $k = n$ -- computes the cardinality of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ and thus the probability that an $n \times n$ matrix is invertible.

Comment: "However, we should be interested in the number of linear subspaces of dimension k." I'm not sure why you say "should".  But if you are interested in that, you should specify it in your question.  Your formula for the number of $k$-dimensional subspaces is correct.

Comment: Summary: in linear algebra one sometimes considers linear independence of ordered tuples and sometimes considers linear indepdence of sets.  Both are natural concepts.  The distinction is also natural on the probabilistic side.  I took "I guess, it depends on how we choose..." to be an invitation to make a choice, and I chose the one that leads in particular to the computation of $\# \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$.  If you want it the other way, **please specify that in your question**.